# Why i can not create vector objects from text file?

Tags: c++, file, class, vector

```
class CTurist
{
private:
    string name;
    string country;
    int age;
public:
    CTurist()
    {
        name = "";
        country = "";
        age = 0;
    }
    CTurist(string n, string c, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        country = c;
        age = a;
    }
    CTurist(const CTurist &t)
    {
        name = t.name;
        country = t.country;
        age = t.age;
    }
    string get_name()
    {
        return name;
    }
    string get_country()
    {
        return country;
    }
    int get_age()
    {
        return age;
    }
    void set_name(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    void set_country(string c)
    {
        country = c;
    }
    void set_age(int a)
    {
        age = a;
    }
    bool operator<(CTurist& t)
    {
        return this->age < t.age;
    }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, CTurist& t)
    {
        istr >> t.name >> t.country >> t.age;
        return istr;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const CTurist& t)
    {
        ostr << "\nName: " << t.name << ", country: " << t.country << ", age: " << t.age;
        return ostr;
    }
};

class CHotel
{
private:
    string hotel_name;
    int num_beds;
    double aver_price;
    vector<vector<CTurist>>v;
public:
    CHotel()
    {
        hotel_name = "";
        num_beds = 0;
        aver_price = 0;
    }
    CHotel(string hn, int nb, double ap, vector<vector<CTurist>>&vec)
    {
        hotel_name = hn;
        num_beds = nb;
        aver_price = ap;
        v = vec;
    }
    CHotel(const CHotel& h)
    {
        hotel_name = h.hotel_name;
        num_beds = h.num_beds;
        aver_price = h.aver_price;
        v = h.v;
    }
    string get_hotel_name()
    {
        return hotel_name;
    }
    int get_num_beds()
    {
        return num_beds;
    }
    double get_aver_price()
    {
        return aver_price;
    }
    vector<vector<CTurist>> get_vector() {
        return v;
    }
    void set_hotel_name(string hn)
    {
        hotel_name = hn;
    }
    void set_num_beds(int nb)
    {
        num_beds = nb;
    }
    void set_aver_price(double ap)
    {
        aver_price = ap;
    }
    bool operator<(CHotel& h)
    {
        return this->aver_price < h.aver_price;
    }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, CHotel& h)
    {
        int n;
        CTurist tur;
        istr >> h.hotel_name >> h.num_beds >> h.aver_price;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
                istr >> n;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; i++) {
                    istr >> tur;
                    v[i].push_back(tur);
                }
            }
        return istr;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const CHotel& h)
    {
        ostr << "Hotel name: " << h.hotel_name << ", number of beds: " << h.num_beds << ", average price: " << h.aver_price;
        for(const auto& it: h.v)
        {
            for (const auto& itr : it)
                ostr << itr;
        }
        return ostr;

    }
    void Output(ostream &ostr)
    {
        ostr << "\nHotel name: " << hotel_name << ", number of beds: " << num_beds << ", average price: " << aver_price;
        for (const auto& it : v)
        {
            for (const auto& itr : it)
                ostr << itr;
        }
    }
};

class CTurLine
{
    string m_line;
    vector<CHotel>m_hoteli;
public:
    CTurLine(string l, vector<CHotel>& vec)
    {
        m_line = l;
        m_hoteli = vec;
    }
    CTurLine(const string& filename)
    {
        ifstream ifile(filename);
        if (ifile.is_open())
        {
            ifile >> m_line;
            copy(istream_iterator<CHotel>(ifile), istream_iterator<CHotel>(), back_inserter(m_hoteli));
        }
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const CTurLine& t)
    {
        ostr << "Turline: " << t.m_line;
        for (const auto& it : t.m_hoteli)
        {
            ostr << it;
        }
        return ostr;
    }
    void Output(ostream &ostr)
    {
        ostr << m_line << endl;
        copy(m_hoteli.begin(), m_hoteli.end(), ostream_iterator<CHotel>(ostr, " "));
    }
};
int main()
{
    try {
        CTurLine tur("data.txt");
        tur.Output(cout);
    }
    catch (exception &e)                //catch(char *c) -AKO E SAMO THROW
    {                                  //{
        cout << e.what() << endl;     //cout<<c<<endl;
    }
}
```

So this is my school project.I have problems with reading objects(vector of vectors) and my program isn't running.The problem is inside friend ostream operator in class CHotel.

I will upload 2 pictures.On the first you will see my text file, and on the second my error list.

I tried to fix it with & as is shown as suggestion in error list,  but it did not help.

Can someone tell me how to fix it?
[text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kpdt.png)
[image: error list]

Albena

Magnolia 54 110 

3

ivan bg 50 

mariya bg 40 

pesho pl 10

3

valeri uk 15 

ivelina uk 35 

gosho pl 31

3

james usa 52 

catrin 45 usa 

pier fr 41

3

raluca ro 60 

kim usa 20 

william usa 18

3

lenka cz 20 

martin cz 26 

adrian pl 65

3

kalina ro 45 

monika sp 40 

jared usa 49

3

daniel bg 17 

teq bg 23 

daniela bg 30

3

milen bg 43 

valentin bg 43 

andrey bg 21

3

adriana usa 19 

gergana uk 21 

vasilena bg 30

3

vanq bg 23 

venci bg 30 

graciela bg 21

3

todorka bg 46 

stanislav bg 34 

martina bg 65

3

conrad usa 26 

borko ro 45 

julia uk 31

Comment: In `friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, CHotel& h)`, you have `v[i].push_back(tur);`, but it should be `h.v[i].push_back(tur);` … PS: Please don't post pictures of errors, copy the errors into the question instead

Comment: Please provide text as text, not as images.

Comment: @ChrisMM okay, i will now for the next post, but when i add h. before the vector this is the message i get :Debug Assertion Failed

Comment: @Samantha That's because the vector `h.v` has zero size. So when you do `h.v[i]` you get an error.

Comment: @john so how should i repair this?

Comment: As already explained, you have to grow `h.v` with (something like) `h.v.push_back({});`. Exacly the same idea as `h.v[i].push_back()`. `h.v` is two dimensional and both dimensions need to grow.

Answer (score 1):

To your original question, you get the error about a reference to non-static member, because in your

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, CHotel& h)
```

function, you have the following line:

```
v[i].push_back(tur);
```

Since this function is not actually part of the `CHotel` class, `v` is not accessible in this manner. It must be changed to:

```
h.v[i].push_back(tur);
```

As pointed out in the comments, this leads to an assertion failed (in VS debug build). This is UB, since `v` is actually size zero. In the outer loop, you need to add a new `vector` to the `v` vector. Thus, in the end, you'd have:

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& istr, CHotel& h)
{
    int n;
    CTurist tur;
    istr >> h.hotel_name >> h.num_beds >> h.aver_price;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        istr >> n;
        h.v.push_back( {} );
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            istr >> tur;
            h.v[i].push_back(tur);
        }
    }
    return istr;
}
```

PS: You also had `i++` in the inner for loop, which should have been `j++`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I finally understood it! I tried to fix it like you said but again: Debug Assertion Failed on the same line where push_back tur

Comment: Can you post the contents of the file as text?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x5114ED76 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project2.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.   this is in my program on that line i said..it is very strange

Comment: i posted my whole text file

Comment: thank you very much! Just one last question: Does it matter if my text file content is not only in 1 line because my txt is on many lines?

Comment: If you're not using `getline`, I don't think it should matter.

Comment: Did you run it on your PC and is it working properly because after everything you said i change my program , fixed the vector and j++ but now i can run it but the output is just Albena(m_line)

Comment: That's the output, yes. I didn't look into why, because that wasn't in the question :P (we try to stick with one question per question)